# How to use '%%%' in a Build.scala file

Tags: sbt, scala.js

I'm getting familiar with using the '%%%' operator in a build.sbt file, but I don't understand how to use it in a build.scala file. I'm getting the following error:

```
value %%% is not a member of String
```

I'm guessing that I have to import the %%% somehow but I don't see how. I tried the following:

```
import org.scalajs.sbtplugin.ScalaJSPlugin._
import ScalaJSKeys._
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: Since Scala.js 0.6.23, you need the following import:

```
import org.portablescala.sbtplatformdeps.PlatformDepsPlugin.autoImport._
```

---

Old answer for Scala.js < 0.6.23:

As documented [here](http://www.scala-js.org/doc/sbt/setup.html), the appropriate imports are

```
import org.scalajs.sbtplugin.ScalaJSPlugin
import org.scalajs.sbtplugin.ScalaJSPlugin.autoImport._
```