# Resolving ScalaJSPlugin from Build.scala and plugins.sbt

Tags: scala, scala.js

I'm trying to make "ScalaJSPlugin" work, to be resolved in:

project/Build.scala

```
 object BuildProject extends Build {
  ..
  lazy val scalaRx = Project(id = "ScalaRX", base = file("scalarx")).enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin).settings(
     version      := "0.1",
     scalaVersion := "2.11.7",

     libraryDependencies ++= scalaRxDependencies
    ) ...
```

In my project/plugins.sbt file, I put.

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-scalajs" % "0.6.8")
```

It fails with with compilation error in Build.scala trying to resolve "ScalaJSPlugin"

There are links to the repo [1](https://github.com/Sergey80/scala-samples/blob/master/project/Build.scala), [2](https://github.com/Sergey80/scala-samples/blob/master/project/plugins.sbt)

for now I keep that changes commented.

Comment: Whats the error msg?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import \`%%%\` in \`Build.scala\` in a scalajs project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29473377/how-to-import-in-build-scala-in-a-scalajs-project)

Comment: seems not to be uncommented anymore now, did you fix the problem?